# RxJS: The signature '(error: any): Observable<never>' of 'throwError' is deprecated.(6387)

Tags: javascript, rxjs

When I try to use `throwError` from inside the `catchError` to return an error, I get the following deprecation message

> The signature '(error: any): Observable' of 'throwError' is deprecated.(6387)

```js
const { Observable, throwError } = rxjs;
const { catchError } = rxjs.operators;

new Observable((observer) => {
  observer.next('first emission');
  observer.error('error emission');
  observer.complete();
}).pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    console.log('Caught error:', error);
    return throwError(error);                // <-- deprecation here
  })
).subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log('Next:', value),
  error: (error) => console.log('Error:', error),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete')
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Deprecation reproduction: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-anqsjt?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for deprecation is explained [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3a6d1643f6ef9cc28cce0051a805b9ce55ceb7a3/src/internal/observable/throwError.ts#L106-L108):

> Support for passing an error value will be removed in v8. Instead, pass a factory function to `throwError(() => new Error('test'))`. This is because it will create the error at the moment it should be created and capture a more appropriate stack trace. If for some reason you need to create the error ahead of time, you can still do that: `const err = new Error('test'); throwError(() => err);`

So we could either do

```js
.pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    return throwError(() => new Error(error));
  })
).subscribe({
  error: (error) => console.log('Error:', error.message)
});
```

or

```js
.pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    return throwError(() => error);
  })
).subscribe({
  error: (error) => console.log('Error:', error)
});
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8ga2ry?file=index.ts)