# After having upgraded an Angular project from 9.1 to 16 I got this error on catch (next.handle(...).catch is not a function)

Tags: angular

I've created an Angular 16 project from scratch, copied all the code files and updated npms.. now at smoke tests I got this error on catch for httpClient.

The interceptor code is

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
} from "@angular/common/http";

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ErrorService } from "@ttgservices/error/error.service";
import { ErrorInfo } from "@ttgdomain/general/errorInfo";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private error: ErrorService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch((response: any) => {
      if (response && response.error) {
        const errorInfo = response.error as ErrorInfo;
        if (errorInfo && errorInfo.message && errorInfo.status) {
          let msg = `An error ocurred. ${errorInfo.message} (error code: ${errorInfo.status})`;
          if (errorInfo.details) {
            msg = `${errorInfo.message}: ${errorInfo.details} (error code: ${errorInfo.status})`;
          }
          this.error.setError(msg);
        }
      }
      return throwError(response);
    });
  }
}
```

With this stacktrace :

```
component-load-base.ts:43 TypeError: next.handle(...).catch is not a function
    at ErrorInterceptor.intercept (error.interceptor.ts:22:38)
    at http.mjs:1614:60
    at Object.handle (http.mjs:1615:40)
    at TokenInterceptor.intercept (token.interceptor.ts:29:17)
    at http.mjs:1614:60
    at http.mjs:1659:16
    at http.mjs:1624:76
    at R3Injector.runInContext (core.mjs:9152:20)
    at http.mjs:1624:57
    at http.mjs:1624:127
```

But the strange thing is that if I do a CTRL+click on catch method is loads the code of the method...

Any suggestion?

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "moonshine",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ci": "yarn install --frozen-lockfile",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:docker": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --base-href=/",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --extract-licenses=true && xcopy web.config dist\\ttg-crm",
    "build:linux": "ng build --configuration production --extract-licenses=true && cp web.config dist/ttg-crm",
    "build:staging": "ng build --configuration=staging --extract-licenses=true && xcopy web.config dist\\ttg-crm",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@material/checkbox": "^15.0.0-canary.b994146f6.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-utils": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.2",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^6.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.6.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-scanner-qrcode": "^1.5.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.20",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.196",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: In Angular 16, instead of using catch, use catchError in your code and see if it works.

Comment: but I need to use RxJS 7 right?

Comment: I saw I'm using a compat library...I remove that one ..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message and the usage of `catch` operator, I'd make an informed guess that you've upgraded from RxJS v4 to RxJS v6.

The operator chaining changed between v4 -> v5. You'd need to chain the operators using the [`.pipe`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe) method. Moreover, you'd need to replace the [`catch`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/6770d24307ed4baaecdbb21cfc178c13e459f42f/doc/api/core/operators/catch.md) operator with [`catchError`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3de56b9d86f22177e1a54d4d367d3235dcd73fb0/src/internal/operators/catchError.ts#L90) operator.

To answer your question from the comments:

> but I need to use RxJS 7 right?

No. The breaking changes were introduced in v5. You seem to be now using v6, so you don't have to necessarily upgrade to v7.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private error: ErrorService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.error) {
          const errorInfo = response.error as ErrorInfo;
          if (errorInfo && errorInfo.message && errorInfo.status) {
            let msg = `An error ocurred. ${errorInfo.message} (error code: ${errorInfo.status})`;
            if (errorInfo.details) {
              msg = `${errorInfo.message}: ${errorInfo.details} (error code: ${errorInfo.status})`;
            }
            this.error.setError(msg);
          }
        }
        return throwError(response);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Also if you were to upgrade to v7, you'd need to rewrite the `throwError` to the following. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70124902/6513921) for more info.

```js
return throwError(() => response);
```